# How to use Gradle to download JAR dependencies on production site?

Tags: jar, gradle

In the hope of finding the solution on Google as it seems a very general task, I've been trying to do this past few weeks but strangely I couldn't find anything!

#### What I'm doing:

I am writing an small application, It will be at most a 20KB JAR file in the end. However it has many dependencies, Hibernate and SLF4J to name a few. Directly including these dependencies with the jar file will make it 9Mb.

#### What is used:

Gradle is used as the build tool. the custom task fatJar creates the jar including all required dependency jar files from (the original) maven repository.

#### The problem

with my slow internet connection I'd rather not to directly include dependencies, but download these them on the server and not my local production site. What would be the Gradle task like to:

- Read the dependencies from jar file
- Download them (I know how to do it during Gradle build task).
- Add them to class path
- Add classpath defined in MANIFEST.mf too
- run the jar, by main class defined in MANIFEST.mf

I've read gradle documentation over and over, but no help.